# Working overseas - Paid locally or USA?

Tags: united-states, banking, non-resident, salary

I will be working in Indonesia but for an American company.  They can pay me directly in Indonesia or in USA.  I asked if they can split my salary between two payments (part to USA, part to Indonesia) but they cannot.  Can anyone offer any advice if I should ask for my salary to be paid into my USA account and make regular transfers to Indonesia, or should I have my salary sent directly to Indonesia.  I will be paying the maximum into my USA, company-match 401k.  Thanks!